# how to hide column in export

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

How to hide the select all(checkbox) column in excel or csv export.

```
{
    checkboxSelection: true,
    suppressMenu: true,
    suppressSorting: true,
    suppressFilter: true,
    width: 30,
    pinned: true,
    suppressExcelExport :true,
    headerCellRenderer: this.selectAllRenderer
},
```

Answer (score 1):

below code will solve your problem

```
var columnsForExport=[];
var allColumns=gridOption.columnApi.getAllColumns();

allColumns.forEach((element:any) => {
    if(element.colId!="#"){
        columnsForExport.push(element.colId)
    }
});
```

Comment: {
    checkboxSelection: true,
    suppressMenu: true,
    suppressSorting: true,
    suppressFilter: true,
    width: 30,
    pinned: true,
    suppressExcelExport :true,
  columnKeys:columnsForExport
},

Answer (score 1):

As for now, the `suppressExcelExport: true` property works only for the entire grid, not the columns!

However there is a nice workaround which will enable any custom column property (e.g. `suppressExcelExport`) to act like a real working property as you asked.

All you need is calling this function on a button click or add [context menu](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/context-menu/) item:

```
function exportActiveColumns() {
    let allColumns = gridOptions.columnApi.getAllColumns();
    let exportColumns = allColumns .filter(col => !col.userProvidedColDef.suppressExcelExport);
    gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel({
        columnKeys: exportColumns,
    });
}
```

Make sure `suppressExcelExport` is `false` for the grid, otherwise there will be no result after calling `exportDataAsExcel` api.

Exact same thing works for CSV.